# Почему условие if с Array.from(new Set()) не срабатывает?

Tags: javascript

Вот пример кода:

```
var arr = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4]);
      if (Array.from(arr) != [] ) {
        console.log(arr);
        arr = new Set();
      }

      console.log(Array.from(arr)); //[]

      if (Array.from(arr) == [] ) {
        console.log(arr); // условие не выполняется
      }
```

Консоль выводит пустой массив, но при этом условие во втором if равно false. Почему?

Comment: Вы сравниваете один массив с другим. Очевидно это false. На наличие элементов есть `.length`

Comment: `console.log( [] == [] );` — тоже выведет false... Это разные пустые массивы) И это тоже будет false — `console.log( [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3] );`